# how to implement R lapply on a data frame object

Tags: r, lapply

I am very new to R and especially to R `apply` family functions.

I have a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(3,4,5))
```

And tried:

```
lapply(df$a,sum)
```

But this doesn't give the sum of the first column of data frame `df`.

However, this line of code does:

```
lapply(df,sum)
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple columns, use `colSums`

```
colSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)
```

and single column, it would be

```
sum(df$a, na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

If we loop over a vector, each element of the `list` have a length of 1, thus the `sum` would be the element itself